# Using mergeinfo to compare branches with different roots

Tags: bash, svn

I am comparing branches with `svn mergeinfo http://myserver.com/branches/FeatureBranch http://myserver.com/branches/UAT --show-revs eligible` which shows if anything is in the feature branch but not in UAT.

However, someone has created a branch from a branch and made 2 commits. When I run the command it lists all the commits from the original branch instead of just the too commits. This is the expected behaviour I believe, however, I would like to just see the two commits.

`svn log` has the `--stop-on-copy` option to just show the two commits in the log so I would like to simulate something like that with the the mergeinfo command. However, not surprisingly, it is not supported.

```
'Subcommand mergeinfo' doesn't accept option '--stop-on-copy'
```

How can I simulate the behaviour I am interested in?
Perhaps some bash to remove anything from the output that is less than the revision of the branch creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the revision range with -r starting from the second branch point.

OP Comment:
This makes the script look like this:

```
echo "Checking if there are commits beyond the code freeze"
svn log --xml --stop-on-copy $UAT|grep msg|cut -d\> -f2|cut -d: -f1|sort -u|while read branch 
do
    if [ "$branch" != "" ]; then        
        echo "Checking branch: $branch"
        branchVersion=$(svn log --xml --stop-on-copy $Branches/$branch|grep revision|tail -1|awk -F\" '{ print $2 }')
        eligibleRevisions=$(svn mergeinfo -r$branchVersion:HEAD $Branches/$branch $UAT  --show-revs eligible)
        if [ "$eligibleRevisions" != "" ]; then   
            echo "Branch $branch Created at $branchVersion"           
            echo "svn mergeinfo -r$branchVersion:HEAD $Branches/$branch $UAT  --show-revs eligible"
            echo "$eligibleRevisions" 
        fi  
    fi  
done
```